# Sorting in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to get the output from my dictionary to be ordered from their values in stead of keys

Question:

ValueCount that accepts a list as a parameter. Your function will return a list of tuples.  Each tuple will contain a value and the number of times that value appears in the list

Desired outcome

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,5,5,4]
    >>> ValueCount(data)
            [(1, 2), (2, 2), (5, 1), (4, 1)]
```

My code and outcome

```
def CountValues(data):
    dict1 = {}
    for number in data:
        if number not in dict1:
            dict1[number] = 1
        else: 
            dict1[number] += 1
    tuple_data = dict1.items()
    lst = sorted(tuple_data)
    return(lst)

>>>[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 2)]
```

How would I sort it ascendingly by using the values instead of keys.

Comment: Instead of manually counting use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and instead of sorting use its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the values(second item in each tuple), specify `key`:

```
sorted(tuple_data, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Or with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
sorted(tuple_data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Also as a side note, your counting code:

```
dict1 = {}
for number in data:
    if number not in dict1:
        dict1[number] = 1
    else: 
        dict1[number] += 1
```

Can be simplified with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
dict1 = collections.Counter(data)
```

With all the above in mind, your code *could* look like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

def CountValues(data):
    counts = Counter(data)
    return sorted(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

print(CountValues([1,2,3,1,2,3,5,5,4]))
# [(4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **sorted** with the help of key parameter. it is not a in-place sorting . Thus it never modifies the original array.

[for more](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-key-or-value/)

```
In [18]:  data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,5,5,4]

In [19]:  from collections import Counter

In [20]: x=Counter(data).items()


#Sorted OUTPUT
In [21]: sorted(list(x), key= lambda i:i[1] )   
Out[21]: [(4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2)]

In [22]: x
Out[22]: dict_items([(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (4, 1)])
```

Comment: If already using a `Counter`, you can use its `most_common` method instead of sorting. If ascending order is required, you can do `Counter(data).most_common()[::-1]`

Answer (score -2):

"Sort" function uses first element of data. 
To sort dictionary by its values you can use for-loop for values:

```
d={1:1,2:2,5:2,4:3,3:2}
x=[]
for i in set(sorted(d.values())):
    for j in sorted(d.items()):
        if j[1]==i:
            x.append(j)
print(x)
```

if you don't convert `sorted(d.values())` to `set{}` , it will check every value, even there are same numbers. For example if your values list is `[1,2,2,3]` , it will check items for value "2" two times and as a result your sorted list will contain repeated data which both have value "2" . But `set{}` keeps only one of each element and in this case, for-loop will check every different value of `d.values()` . And if there are items with a same value, code will sort them by keys because of `sorted(d.items())` .
(to understand better you can use this code without that `set{}` and  use `d.items()` instead of `sorted(d.items())`)

Comment: This is not a good way to sort by the values, it is needlessly inefficient, this can be done in O(M*logN) time, but here you are doing something like O(M**2*(logN )**2)